# ChakraUI inside chrome extension style all pages

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, emotion, chakra-ui

I have small issue realted to ChakraUI.
I try to create chrome extension wit it, unfortunettly all default chakra theme apply to all pages, theres any way to prevent it? i try to use cssVarsRoot, also read about @emotion but i cannot find solution.

```
popupRoot && 
  ReactDOM.render(
      <ChakraProvider resetCSS cssVarsRoot="#popup-root">
        <PopupComponent />
      </ChakraProvider>,
    popupRoot
  );
```

Comment: Did you end up finding an answer to this? I am having the same issue